# How do I let a user browse HTML/WebSite content without launching the browser (need an inline browser)?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm creating an app on Windows Phone 7 that lets folks read offline HTML content. Is there a way to show an inline browser or HTML viewing control?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `WebBrowser` control allows you to display arbitrary HTML.

There are two methods on the `WebBrowser` control you can use to display HTML:

1. `Navigate()` will display the contents of a file located at the supplied URL. This file can be in `IsolatedStorage` or on a server.
2. `NavigateToString()` will display the html string you give it.

In your case I'm guessing you'd use a `WebClient` object to download the webpage to offline storage, then the `Navigate` method to display it.

However, the benefit of `NavigateToString` is that you can munge the string on the way in to do some cool (or essential) stuff like style the page so it matches perfectly with the current phone theme, or catch all link clicks and make them pop in the external browser (otherwise they load in the very same `WebBrowser` control).

I've documented the details of styling and link clickery [here](http://www.ben.geek.nz/2010/07/integrated-links-and-styling-for-windows-phone-7-webbrowser-control/).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there's a `WebBrowser` control in `Microsoft.Phone.Controls`

If you then save your (offline) files to `IsolatedStorage` you can then view the file via a call like this from code:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("offline-file-name.html", UriKind.Relative));
```

Things to note:

- You can use directories within isolated storage. Just specify the whole path in the Uri.
- If navigating between offline pages, all paths must be relative.